# Probability calculation for salary of both employees over $1500, if known mean and variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know the **mean** and the **variance** of 130 employees in an industry and **I have to calculate the probability that 2 workers selected randomly have both salary above $1500**. I also know the salary of every emploee in this indtry, from which I can calculate the mean and the variance.
Can you please give me a tip, because I'a little confused.

Comment: To clarify, do you know the sample mean and variance or the population mean and variance? Further, are you assuming the salaries follow a particular distribution, like the normal distribution?

Comment: I know the sample mean and variance. I don't assume that the salaries follow a particular distribution. My question is, since I know mean and variance, I think that the distribution is normal (??), and I know how to calculate probability for one worker to have salary above 1500, but I don't know how to calculate this probability for both workers to have salary above 1500?

Comment: knowing the sample mean and variance does not allow you to conclude that the distribution is normal—this must be justified by the CLT or just assumed from the beginning. So if this is the case, and additionally the salaries of each worker are assumed to be independent, then $P(\text{two workers above 1500})=P(S>1500)^2$, where $S$ is the salary of an individual.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have $a$ employees with salary $\ge\$1500$ and $b$ with salary $<\$1500$ (you said you have access to these numbers). There are ${a+b\choose 2}$ ways to choose two employees and ${a\choose 2}$ ways to choose two with high salary. So your probabiliy is

$$p=\frac{a\choose 2}{a+b\choose 2}=\frac{a(a-1)}{(a+b)(a+b-1)}.$$